# How can I move overbraces to the left on a matrix?

Tags: matrices, labels, overbrace

I am trying to move the overbraces on $E_1$ and $E_2$ to the left a little bit. Can you help me out?
[image]

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand\coolover[2]{\mathrlap{\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{%
                    \begin{matrix} #2 \end{matrix}}}^{\mbox{$#1$}}}}#2}

\newcommand\coolunder[2]{\mathrlap{\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
                    \begin{matrix} #2 \end{matrix}}}_{\mbox{$#1$}}}}#2}

\newcommand\coolleftbrace[2]{%
    #1\left\{\vphantom{\begin{matrix} #2 \end{matrix}}\right.}

\newcommand\coolrightbrace[2]{%
    \left.\vphantom{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}}\right\}#2}


\begin{document}
\[ 
E=
\begin{matrix}
\coolleftbrace{R_1}{\multirow{2}{*}{$E_1$}}\\
\coolleftbrace{r}{}\\
\coolleftbrace{R_2}{0}
\end{matrix}%
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\coolover{C_1}{\multirow{2}{*}{$E_1$}}   &  \coolover{C_2}{0}  \\ \cline{2-2}
&  \multirow{2}{*}{$E_2$}  \\ \cline{1-1} 
0  &        \\
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your sample code doesn't compile, as it doesn't load the `multirow` and `mathtools` packages.

Comment: Thank you! I just have edited!

Answer (score 10):

With `nicematrix` (needed two compilations):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt,
            pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
            post=moveto, post length=1pt,
            raise=#1},
            thick,
            pen colour=black},
B/.default=7pt
        }

\begin{document}
    \[  
\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}C|C}%
[create-extra-nodes, margin, extra-margin=1pt ,
code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -large]
        \draw[B={3pt}] (1-1.north west) -- node[above=5pt] {$C_1$} (1-1.north east);
        \draw[B={3pt}] (1-2.north west) -- node[above=5pt] {$C_2$} (1-2.north east);
        \draw[B] (1-1.south west) -- node[left=8pt] {$R_1$} (1-1.north west);
        \draw[B] (2-1.south west) -- node[left=8pt] {$E=\quad r$} (2-1.north west);
        \draw[B] (3-1.south west) -- node[left=8pt] {$R_3$} (3-1.north west);
              \end{tikzpicture}
              }
]  
\Block{2-1}{E_1}    & 0                 \\  
    \cline {2-2}
                    & \Block{2-1}{E_2}  \\
   \cline {1-1}
0                   &                   \\
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may more liked, that descriptions of the rows would be on the right side:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt,
            pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
            post=moveto, post length=1pt,
            raise=#1},
            thick,
            pen colour=black},
B/.default=7pt
        }

\begin{document}
    \[  E = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}C|C}%
[create-extra-nodes, margin, extra-margin=1pt ,
code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -large]
        \draw[B={3pt}] (1-1.north west) -- node[above=5pt] {$C_1$} (1-1.north east);
        \draw[B={3pt}] (1-2.north west) -- node[above=5pt] {$C_2$} (1-2.north east);
        \draw[B] (1-2.north east) -- node[right=8pt] {$R_1$} (1-2.south east);
        \draw[B] (2-2.north east) -- node[right=8pt] {$r$}   (2-2.south east);
        \draw[B] (3-2.north east) -- node[right=8pt] {$R_3$} (3-2.south east);
              \end{tikzpicture}
              }
]
\Block{2-1}{E_1}    & 0                 \\
    \cline {2-2}
                    & \Block{2-1}{E_2}  \\
   \cline {1-1}
0                   &                   \\
\end{bNiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: I am trying use the package 'nicematrix' , but it doesn't work since I have to manually install 'nicematrix.sty', apparently. I have got the package from the website, and try to install it on my mac by googling how to manually install it. But, I am being stuck for a long time. Can you help me out if you have any idea what to do? I tried with the 'tex live utility'

Comment: @kswim, I haven't mac and so I haven't any experiences with its LaTeX. I'm very sorry, but in this I can't help you. I use MikTeX on Windows machine. I has utility "console"  by which you can simple install (with its package manager) missed packages.

Comment: Thank you for reply though!

Answer (score 5):

You can make the construction using 4 columns:

1. Left row indices (*R<sub>1</sub>*, *r* and *R<sub>2</sub>*) and left brace [;
2. First column in matrix and centre divider;
3. Second column in matrix and centre divider (overlapping that of first column); and
4. Right brace ].

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
  E = \left.\begin{array}{@{} r<{\bigl\{} @{}}
    R_1  \\ r \\ R_2
  \end{array}\right[
  \overbrace{
    \begin{array}{c |}
      \strut \\ \strut\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$E_1$} \\
      \hline
      \strut 0
    \end{array}
  }^{C_1}
  \!% Join two math elements
  \hspace{-.4pt}% Overlap left column rule with previous column's right column rule
  \overbrace{
    \begin{array}{| c}
      \strut 0 \\
      \hline
      \strut \\ \strut\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$E_2$}
    \end{array}
  }^{C_2}
  \!
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{array}{ @{}c@{} }
    \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut
  \end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciated that!

Comment: Do I have to load something more? It is not working..

Comment: `\nulldelimeterspace` -> `\nulldelimiterspace`. Sorry, changed that.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!